# jQuery — Help me make this shorthand more verbose

Tags: jquery

Hi this may be unusual, but I need to expand this code to a more readable form so I can undertsand what it's doing, then I can maybe expand on the code to make it do what I need it to do. Here's the code: in full (taken from [here](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-hashchange/examples/hashchange/))

```
$(function(){

 // Bind an event to window.onhashchange that, when the hash changes, gets the
 // hash and adds the class "selected" to any matching nav link.
 $(window).hashchange( function(){
   var hash = location.hash;

// Set the page title based on the hash.
document.title = 'The hash is ' + ( hash.replace( /^#/, '' ) || 'blank' ) + '.';

// Iterate over all nav links, setting the "selected" class as-appropriate.
$('.article a').each(function(){
  var that = $(this);
  that[ that.attr( 'href' ) === hash ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass' ]( 'selected' );
});
})

// Since the event is only triggered when the hash changes, we need to trigger
// the event now, to handle the hash the page may have loaded with.
$(window).hashchange();

});
```

The specific line I dont understand is this one:

```
  that[ that.attr( 'href' ) === hash ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass' ]( 'selected' );
```

This is just unreadable to me at my stage of development. I'd like to learn though. 
I mean, i get what it's doing 100%... but i dont know how to affect the parent of "that" with this kind of code, I dont know where i'd put "parent"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
that[ that.attr( 'href' ) === hash ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass' ]( 'selected' );
```

is a **horrible** line of code which uses the *ternary* (`?:`) operator to pick a function to call.

In long hand it would be:

```
if (that.attr('href') === hash) {
    that.addClass('selected');
} else {
    that.removeClass('selected');
}
```

The original code takes advantage of the fact that

- `$(this).foo` is the same as `$(this)[foo]`, so
- `that.foo` is the same as `that[foo]`, so
- `that.foo(args)` is the same as `that[foo](args)`

and then to further complicate things, they made `foo` a conditional expression!

Comment: ok awesome, thanks to you both! It's like code breakers in here :)

Comment: Is it horrible because it's less readable, or because it's a hack?

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen that construction before. It's effectively

```
if (that.attr('href') === hash) {
    that.addClass('selected');
} else {
    that.removeClass('selected');
}
```

using the fact that `jQuery.addClass === jquery['addClass']` and both's value is a function that can be invoked.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.fn.extend({
    activeClass: function(className, active) {
        this[active ? 'addClass': 'removeClass'](className);
        return this;
    }
});
```

then u can use it like

```
$('body').activeClass('some-class-name',true);
```

if last var will be false, class from body will be removed